# How can I run Assistant demo in bootup in my AIY?

Tags: python, raspbian, google-aiy

I'm building Google Assistant in my AIY Voice Kit V1, and want to make it respond when it booted up. But I have problems with making it in reality.
Being new in both Linux and Raspberry Pi, now I have no idea what to do.

In the beginning, I followed all the official instructions. That was easy, and I succeeded to run the demo in `~/AIY-projects-python/src/examples/voice`

Then I tried to make it run when the system is booted, simply by making `assist.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system` and this is what it contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=Assist @ reboot
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=systemd-timesyncd.service
After=systemd-timesyncd.service

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Type=simple
Restart=always
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/AIY-projects-python/src/examples/voice/main.py --language en-US

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I created the file `main.py` with this:`$ cp assistant_library_with_button_demo.py main.py`
Then I made it enable:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable assist.service
```

And finally, I rebooted it with excitement. But it answered neither by saying 'Okay, Google!' nor by clicking the button.

Feeling something wrong, I typed this in the terminal:

```
$ sudo systemctl status assist.service
```

And I found the error code saying:

```
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x75b4af70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

I can't even understand what the error code exactly means. I need someone's advice. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I am going to format my SD card and do it from scratch by following the official guide https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice-v1/ I will tell you if it works.

Comment: YEAHHHHH! I started from scratch and finally done this by taking a look at https://youtu.be/dFL4ePKWfic I am so happy to see my AIY Voice Kit finally responding when I ask!